# Why is html input field not being validated before post

Tags: javascript, html

So in the html body I have both

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateMelco(form) {
    toReturn=true;
  if (form.melco.value.length==0) {
    alert("Please enter your Melco serial no");
    toReturn=false;
  }
  return toReturn;
}
</script>
```

and

```
<tr>
<td valign="top"><b>SongKong for Melco  (Melco discount)</b>
</td>
<td  valign="top">£40 ($50 USD)
</td>
<td  valign="top">
<form name="paypalpro" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit="return validateMelco()" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="5UC5NAYZ6JZR8">
<input alt="PayPal" type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" border="0" name="submit">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
Melco Serial No:<input type="textfield" name="melco"/>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
```

Yet a user can click on the button without entering anything into the input field, no alert is displayed and the form is posted. Why isn't the JavaScript validation kicking in?

Comment: Why check the length of the value when you can just check if the value is empty? Seems like an unnecessary part.

Comment: @AmericanSlime the real validation hasnt been done yet, but the issue was why the validation (whatever it is) wasnt being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
<form name="paypalpro" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit="return validateMelco()" method="post">
```

to

```
<form name="paypalpro" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit="return validateMelco(this)" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the function with no arguments, but it expects an argument that identifies the form. So it can't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>When you submit the form, a function is triggered which alerts some text.</p>

<tr>
<td valign="top"><b>SongKong for Melco  (Melco discount)</b>
</td>
<td  valign="top">£40 ($50 USD)
</td>
<td  valign="top">
<form name="paypalpro" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit="return validateMelco()" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="5UC5NAYZ6JZR8">
<input alt="PayPal" type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" border="0" name="submit">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
Melco Serial No:<input type="textfield" name="melco"/>
</form>
</td>
</tr>

<script>
function validateMelco(form) {
    toReturn=true;

  if (document.forms["paypalpro"]["melco"].value == "") {
    alert("Please enter your Melco serial no");
    toReturn=false;
  }
  return toReturn;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The form object has not been passed to the function "validateMelco()" for accessing the form elements . So I have used the javascript document object to access the form using 'document.forms["paypalpro"]["melco"]'.

Comment: not going to work if `validateMelco` is expecting a form as a parameter, and your `onsubmit` doesn't provide a form parameter

Comment: I am using the DOM so no need of the parameter. The code is working as it should. :)

Comment: Just dumping code is not helpful. Explain the problem, then explain the solution.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am a beginner here. Sorry for not explaining. I will keep this in mind in my future answers. :)

Comment: You could edit an explanation into _this_ answer. Why only start in the future?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have the already added the explanation. :)